# Full width Panels in Bootstrap V2 "boxed" (1170px) layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I am looking into a future project and I want to build it with bootstrap. I want it to be a boxed ( non-fluid ) layout limited to 1170px ... [actually on a side note I'm currently working with bootstrap V2 because I haven't looked properly at V3 yet but eventually I will work out the same or similar thing out in V3].

So what I need is to have full width panels ( these are quite popular lately in "flat design") with constrained content. That is ... all the content would be limited to a max width of 1170px but the backgrounds would be spanning the full width of the browser.

So I know this markup works but a) is it OK to have nested "container" divs like i've done  and b) I haven't seen this technique before ... is there any better way (more standard way) that I might be missing ... and I appreciate that it may be better to start with version 3 but I would rather work this out in V2 first for my old projects if for nothing else

```
<div class="container-fluid" >

    <div class="container" >
        <div class="row">
          <div class="span12"><h2>Boxed" Bar ( limited to 1170px)</h2></div>  
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="row" style="background:#666">
      <div class="span12"><h2>Full Width Bar with no limits to content</h2></div>  
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="background:yellow">
        <div class="container" >
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12"><h2>Full Width Bar with content limited to 1170px</h2></div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a premium bootstrap marketplace and analyzed some of the themes on there. It looks like something along these lines is a better model.

```
<div class="my-own-wrapper" > <!-- eg 100% width to wrap entire site -->

    <div class="container" >
        <div class="row">
          <div class="span12"><h2>Boxed" Bar ( limited to 1170px)</h2></div>  
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="whatever" style="background:#666"> <!-- non bootrap div 100% width -->
         <div><h2>Full Width Bar with no limits to content</h2></div>  
    </div>

    <div class="whatever" style="background:yellow">
        <div class="container" > <!-- wrapping bootstrap scaffolding in display div -->
           <div class="row"> 
                <div class="span12"><h2>Full Width Bar with content limited to 1170px</h2></div> 
           </div> 
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Obviously it might be better to use some html5 elements too.